How to get the determinant of the metric in xAct?
I want tocalculate the determinant of a metric
DefManifold[M4, 4, Complement[IndexRange[a, q], {g, k, h}]];
DefChart[coor, M4, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}, 
  ChartColor -> Black];
met = CTensor[{{-(1 - 2/3*\[CapitalLambda]0*r[]^2), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
     1/((1 - 2/3*\[CapitalLambda]0*r[]^2)), 0, 0}, {0, 0, r[]^2, 
     0}, {0, 0, 0, r[]^2*Sin[\[Theta][]]^2}}, {-coor, -coor}];
DefConstantSymbol[{\[CapitalLambda]0, k, \[Tau]}]
SetCMetric[met, coor, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}];
CD = CovDOfMetric[met];
$Assumptions = {1 > t[] > 0, 1 > r[] > 0, 0 <= \[Theta][] <= Pi, 
   0 <= \[Phi][] <= 2 Pi};
Ricci[CD][{1, coor}, {1, coor}]
Detmet[CD][]

I use CTensor command to define the metric components, and Ricci[CD][{1, coor}, {1, coor}] could get the Ricci tensor, however, how to get the determinant of the metric?
Thanks.
